# SSRS Encryption with VBA

Tags: vba, encryption, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

So I have an SSRS report with a field called member_ID. When a user clicks on the member_ID I need it to hyperlink to an external website.

Due to the nature of the member_ID I need this to be encrypted.

In order to get it to go to an external site. I'm using the `Action-> Go To URL` Property.

However, I'm confused on how the encryption will take place at this level...I also identified a section in the report properties called Code where you can write custom code. But I'm not too familiar with VBA. **Any idea on how to accomplish this**?

I've googled VBA code that does the AES encryption but **where do I apply it**? **What if there's an existing function there**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple functions in the **CODE** section. Each will start with **FUNCTION FunctionName** (ByVal InputVariable as VarType) as VarType
and end with **END FUNCTION** to separate them. If your code takes an ID and encrypts it, there should be one InputVariable that would be your member_ID.

Example Function:

```
Private bOddRow(10) As Boolean 

Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean, ByVal Type AS INTEGER) As String 
  If Toggle Then bOddRow(Type) = Not bOddRow(Type) 
  If bOddRow(Type) Then 
                Return OddColor 
  Else 
               Return EvenColor 
  End If 
End Function
```

This function is used by using Code.FunctionName with the InputVariables in parenthesis -

```
=CODE.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 0, 0)
```

If your function name is **AESEncrpyt**, you would use something like:

```
="http://www.yoururl.com/something.asp?Member=" & CODE.AESEncrpyt(Fields!MemberID.Value)
```

for your link Action.

Comment: Thank you This last line in the Action is just what I needed!

Comment: Can you tell me what the fully qualified variable name is to pull a variable from a dataset? Like Datasets.NameOfDataSet!VariableName?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - datasets have fields not variables. They would usually be referenced by using **Fields!MemberID.Value** in a table or other object. To reference it outside of table (or object) you can use First(Fields!MemberID.Value, "DataSet1") to get the first instance.

Comment: like this - Public Function AESEncrypt( Datasets.MemberPanelData!Member_Member_ID_.Value)
End Function

Comment: No - that's where a variable name for the function is used in the code. You put the field in the function call for the cell's Action expression - **=CODE.AESEncrpyt(Fields!MemberID.Value)**. If you look at my **AlternateColor** example, **OddColor** is the variable the function uses. When the **=CODE.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 0, 0)** expression is hit, **WHITE** is used for the **OddColor** vaiable.

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind going to chat. I think I need clarification on a few items, but other than that super helpful! Appreciate it.

Comment: OK. Which chat? I've never used it.